# CI/CD Github Workflow not finding build directory

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions, vps

I am currently writing my first CI/CD workflow with Github Actions.

I try to build the application inside the runners workspace and then only copy the docker-compose file and the .dist/ directory with the build artifacts to my vps and start a docker container there.

The build steps are successful, but I struggle to copy the build directory (./dist/*) to my vps.
It tells me that the tar archive is empty...

here is my workflow

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout Repository to the runner's workspace.
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # Set up Node.js on runner's workspace.
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 20.10.0

      # Install dependencies, build and test.
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm ci

      - name: Build and test
        run: |
          npm run build

      - name: List Dist Contents
        run: ls -R ./dist

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to VPS
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          source: |
            ./dist/*
            ./docker-compose.prod.yml
          target: "/usr/src/app"

      - name: Execute remote deployment script
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            # Change directory to the app folder
            cd /usr/src/app

            # Stop and remove the container
            docker-compose down

            # Set environment variables stored in Github secrets
            echo "VITE_BASE_URL=${VITE_BASE_URL}" > .env
            echo "DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}" > .env
            echo "NODE_PORT=${NODE_PORT}" > .env
            echo "SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}" > .env
            echo "REFRESH_SECRET_KEY=${REFRESH_SECRET_KEY}" > .env

            # start container and detach
            docker-compose up -d
```

The workflow fails with this message

```
drone-scp version: v1.6.14
tar all files into /tmp/bgHcjxzAcm.tar.gz
tar: empty archive
exit status 1
```

I logged the dist content right after the build step and it looks totally fine everythink is created. Not sure what iam doing wrong here.

UPDATE:

tried using one job.

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout Repository to the runner's workspace.
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # Set up Node.js on runner's workspace.
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 20.10.0

      # Install dependencies, build and test.
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm ci

      - name: Build and test
        run: |
          npm run build

      - name: List Dist Contents
        run: ls -R ./dist

      - name: Deploy to VPS
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          source: |
            ./dist/*
            ./docker-compose.prod.yml
          target: "/usr/src/app"

      - name: Execute remote deployment script
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            # Change directory to the app folder
            cd /usr/src/app

            # Stop and remove the container
            docker-compose down

            # Remove old .env file
            rm .env

            # Set environment variables stored in Github secrets
            echo "VITE_BASE_URL=${VITE_BASE_URL}" > .env
            echo "DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}" > .env
            echo "NODE_PORT=${NODE_PORT}" > .env
            echo "SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}" > .env
            echo "REFRESH_SECRET_KEY=${REFRESH_SECRET_KEY}" > .env

            # start container and detach
            docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: The jobs are run on different runner machines. You have to [share data between jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow) to make them available e.g. via artifacts. In your particular example, you can first combine both jobs into one to see how that works. Once everything is fine, you can then decide if you need separate jobs or not.

Comment: unfortunately I get the same error, even if I only use one job.

Comment: In the official [examples](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action?tab=readme-ov-file#example), the `source` is a CSV e.g. `source: 'dist/*,docker-compose.prod.yml'`.

Comment: Yes thats it, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Azeem for the answer!

I had to use Comma-Separated Values (CSV) for the source...

[here are the docs](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action?tab=readme-ov-file#example), should have red them. Sorry!